# Pop!_OS make windows fullscreen (not F11)

Tags: qemu, window-manager, nautilus, pop-os, fullscreen

On my Pop!_OS machine (Ubuntu derivative) I sometimes use the full-screen mode in browsers to focus more using the <kbd>F11</kbd> key.

Now, running macOS as a VM via sosumi, I'm in the need of making that QEMU window fullscreen, but <kbd>F11</kbd> won't do the work.

I noticed that I also can't make Nautilus (file manager) fullscreen with <kbd>F11</kbd>. Is there something I could use to make that window fullscreen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like <kbd>F11</kbd> is a shortcut that your browser provides by default, not Pop!_OS. I just tested this in a Pop!_OS VM with Firefox and that seemed to be the case.

You should be able to add a keyboard shortcut for 'Toggle fullscreen mode' by following [the guide here on System76's site](https://support.system76.com/articles/keyboard-shortcuts).

In short:

1. Open Settings
2. Click "Keyboard" on the left sidebar
3. Under Keyboard Shortcuts, click "Customize Shortcuts"
4. Search for "Toggle fullscreen mode"; it should say "Disabled" at the right.
5. Click the three dots again and click "Add shortcut"
6. Press the desired key combination for fullscreen, then click "Set".

Test out the new shortcut in Nautilus and QEMU.

Answer (score 0):

In QEMU, to go fullscreen:

> **[Ctrl-Alt-f](https://qemu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/system/keys.html)**
>
> Toggle full screen

When you are in QEMU, it passes keystrokes to the VM by default. So, to use a shortcut for QEMU itself, it needs to start with Ctrl-Alt (or Ctrl-Alt-Shift) modifier.